# named_scope for sum of column in related table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sum, has-many, named-scope

My SQL skills are laughable at best, which is why Rails and ActiveRecord make my life a lot easier. This time, however, it probably represents a crutch that keeps me from understanding what's going on in the back end in order to know what to feed named_scope.

I'm trying to return the top 10 records of a table that represent the highest scoring "actors" in a game. Score is calculated via Actor>Acts>Decsisons.point_value

I can get the score for any individual actor easily enough, but the joins and sum are above my SQL understanding in order to scope it for the top 10 out of the whole db.

Here is the Actor model as I have it currently:

```
class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :acts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :decisions, :through => :acts, :order => 'created_at'

  named_scope :high_scores, {
    :conditions => {:finished => true}, 
    :joins => "INNER JOIN acts ON actor.id = acts.actor_id INNER JOIN decisions on decision.id = decision.act_id", 
    :group => 'actor.id',
    :select =>'actors.*, SUM(acts.decisions.point_value) AS score', 
    :order => "score DESC", 
    :limit => 10
  }

end
```

After trying out a few things based on some posts here and on some other sites, I'm obviously not grasping what's going on or what named_scope needs to connect the dots. Some clarity would be much appreciated. Thanks.

*Edit: Updated named_scope to what I currently have

This now gives me the following error:

> Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'acts.decisions.point_value' in 'field list': SELECT actors.*, SUM(acts.decisions.point_value) AS score FROM `actors`  INNER JOIN acts ON actor.id = acts.actor_id INNER JOIN decisions on decision.id = decision.act_id WHERE (`actors`.`finished` = 1)  GROUP BY actor.id ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: i would suggest though that if you're going to have a really complex sql statement, why not just use execute statement then tie it to a class function? it's the same anyways, right? just a thought

Comment: you'd be correct in that it would work equally well (and maybe better since the abstraction layer of ActiveRecord wouldn't be there to get in the way), problem being complex SQL statements are nowhere near my ability. That's why I was hoping there'd be something Rails-y that would hold my hand. I'll dig in and see if I can sort out a straight-up SQL statement that'll get me where I need to be in the meantime.

Comment: maybe you can ask for that particular statement here in SO? i am not a SQL guru myself and i actually thought that a complex statement like that can easily be turned into a real sql statement. anyway that's what my boss usually does(he's also a coder) and i do believe that it's a far more efficient way(since joins tend to slow down..doubly so with the rails wrapper)

Comment: I think what I'm actually going to do is just put the final scores in a column since they won't change after their game has finished, and if they do, it won't matter. That'll make a lookup a simple matter of order by score and limit 10 instead of calculating things across joins and summing concurrently based on the entire db. I tried running a similar SQL statement in Sequel Pro and it took forever, and that was without the SUM operator even coming into play. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set final scores in a table column instead, as it seemed to be less resource intensive.